# If not exists statement in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, select, exists

How to write if not exists statement in sql server 2005 for the following condition

If @MeasurementId say values (1,2,3) those are the existing values the below statement work
but when @MeasurementId=0 it doesn't seem to work...

```
If not exists(select Mat_Id,MeasurementId from MaterialQuantity where 
 Mat_Id=@Id and MeasurementId=@MeasurementId)
```

However the above statement doesn't seem to work if have `NULL` values in `MeasurementId` column. Mind you `MeasurementId` is not a ForeignKey here...

How to assign `NULL` if `@MeasurementId` is 0 or use `@MeasurementId` as it is in the 
`where` statement...

This is my [MaterialQuantity table](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6e784b3275.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood, I think you're after the [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325(SQL.90).aspx) syntax:

```
If not exists(select Mat_Id,MeasurementId from MaterialQuantity where 
 Mat_Id=@Id and ISNULL(MeasurementId, 0) =@MeasurementId)
```